# How to set individual locations for screenshots and screen recordings

Tags: screen-capture, quicktime

So, <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> opens up a dialog containing various options, notably where you want **screenshots** to be saved. However, when I open up `QuickTime Player`, to record **videos**, that location is somewhat tied to the screenshots location.

Changing the location through QuickTime player changes the Screenshot location to the same folder, and changing the location through `Grab (keybind)` makes videos save to my desktop.

Is this one of those behaviors where I have to just "deal with it" or "file feedback with Apple"? Or is there some way where I can set individual directories through `Terminal`?

Comment: If your screenshot destination folder changes often then one workaround is to open Finder in desired folder, make sure that 'Show Floating Thumbnail' is enabled in Options and after taking screenshot/video drag and drop thumbnail into Finder folder. I use this way in cases when I need to make one-two screenshot and save them in specific folder - for me it's simpler than to change 'Save to' location and after taking screenshot(s) changing back.